# How does Bitcoin transaction validation work with scriptSig and sciptPubKey?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I'm working through this example from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction

```
Input:
Previous tx: f5d8ee39a430901c91a5917b9f2dc19d6d1a0e9cea205b009ca73dd04470b9a6
Index: 0
scriptSig: 304502206e21798a42fae0e854281abd38bacd1aeed3ee3738d9e1446618c4571d10
90db022100e2ac980643b0b82c0e88ffdfec6b64e3e6ba35e7ba5fdd7d5d6cc8d25c6b241501

Output:
Value: 5000000000
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 404371705fa9bd789a2fcd52d2c580b65d35549d
OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

So basically:

```
Sig = 304502206e21798a42fae0e854281abd38bacd1aeed3ee3738d9e1446618c4571d10
Pub Key = 90db022100e2ac980643b0b82c0e88ffdfec6b64e3e6ba35e7ba5fdd7d5d6cc8d25c6b241501
```

OP_DUP, then OP_HASH160

When I HASH160 (i.e. RIPEMD160(SHA256()) the Pub Key, I get `6f6c7697c8f93d72d3d8286195dd2c261bdef075` and not `404371705fa9bd789a2fcd52d2c580b65d35549d`.

Using https://md5calc.com, I get the following:

```
SHA256 (90db022100e2ac980643b0b82c0e88ffdfec6b64e3e6ba35e7ba5fdd7d5d6cc8d25c6b241501) = 9fb78bdfd748eefc1ab6ff9dd16611f9fc86be5bf12483da612c34887501f195

RIPEME160 (9fb78bdfd748eefc1ab6ff9dd16611f9fc86be5bf12483da612c34887501f195) = 6f6c7697c8f93d72d3d8286195dd2c261bdef075
```

I must be missing a few steps in there?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You encoded the hexadecimal representation of the binary data, not the binary data itself. You need to sha256() and ripemd160() the actual binary data.

Comment: So I'm supposed to covert 90db022100e2ac980643b0b82c0e88ffdfec6b64e3e6ba35e7ba5fdd7d5d6cc8d25c6b241501 to binary and then run  HASH160 on that? I still didn't get the right output :(

Comment: Not just that, you convert EVERYTHING to binary.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I feel that I'm close to understanding it. Could you please elaborate further? What do you mean by convert everything to binary? Like the entire transaction? Then what?